# How to solve Firebase unspecified index error for orderByChild?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am getting the following error:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "answers/dodzzdzodzdz" at /questions to your security rules for better performance. I tried everything but still not working ?

my database rules:

```
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,

    "questions": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
        ".indexOn": ["answers/uid","author","timestamp"],
       "answers":{
          "$uid":{
         ".indexOn":["uid","question"] ,   
      }

       }
```

my code :

```
 const ref = FirebaseRef.child('questions');

    const UID = Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    ref
      .orderByChild('answers/' + UID)
      .limitToLast(this.state.limit)
      .once('value', snapshot => {
        console.log('FireB ', snapshot);
```

my database :

```
       "my_answers" : {
    "yrpgRXZ8LMbzGbBGs3M0WZ1V0WY2" : {
      "-LswFeY4lyIvX4DFFNue" : {
        "answers" : "Www",
        "date_add" : 1572970139448,
        "question" : "2"
      }
    }
  },
  "my_questions" : {
    "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12" : {
      "-LswFbyh-SP_vuj13MK_" : {
        "date_add" : 1572969021413,
        "question" : "1"
      },
      "-LswFeY4lyIvX4DFFNue" : {
        "date_add" : 1572969031933,
        "question" : "2"
      }
    }
  },
  "questions" : {
    "-LswFbyh-SP_vuj13MK_" : {
      "author" : "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12",
      "date_add" : 1572969021413,
      "question" : "1"
    },
    "-LswFeY4lyIvX4DFFNue" : {
      "answer" : {
        "yrpgRXZ8LMbzGbBGs3M0WZ1V0WY2" : {
          "answer" : "Www",
          "date_add" : 1572970139448
        }
      },
      "author" : "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12",
      "date_add" : 1572969031933,
      "question" : "2"
    }
  },
```

Beyond this error, more generally in this database, there will be users who post questions , and responders who responds to question ! so i did a my_questions for list of questions by user , my_answers for list of answers by responders , and questions public list who will get update when responders answers to the question (adding answer : ) there is a lot of duplicate data but i read thats the things to do with firebase ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `orderByChild` call is requesting an ordering (starting at `questions/`) based on `answers/dodzzdzodzdz` (e.g. some *specific* UID), but you are trying to create an index on the string `answers/uid`.  The error message is telling you that you need an index on the specific thing you are running the query on.

Without a clearer idea about what you are trying to actually achieve, its difficult to suggest a real solution.  Certainly, adding an explicit index on the requested UID would work, but seems unlikely to be correct in this case, as you presumably want this to work for any UID.

Alternatively, if you are trying to just order by the keys of all the objects under `'questions/answers/' + UID` this could work, and doesn't require an index. (I do note that this hierarchy isn't actually in the data you provided, I'm modeling it based on your original query).

```js
ref.child('answers/' + UID).orderByKey().limitToLast(this.state.limit)
  .once('value', snapshot => {    
    console.log('FireB ', snapshot);
  });
```

Comment: im actually working on other structure of my database ! can you give me advice ?

Comment: It depends as generally the SO format doesn't do so well with design review type questions (it can be hard to identify a "correct answer" to them).  If you edit your question to show your current database structure and expected output, I can try to give you a better answer to this question though.

Comment: Thanks for adding the database data.  Please also append to the question what a correct result might be for what you want the code you asked about to achieve.  I'm a little confused because (a) there is no `questions/answers` part of the hierarchy and (b) you only have a single answer in the database, so sorting it won't really be interesting.